# Добавление autocomplete в TextBox без jQuery и Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net

Всем привет !

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу найти решения, как сделать `AutoComplete`в `ASP .NET` (живой поиск) без `jQuery` и без `Ajax`.

То есть, в WinForms было бы так:

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source; 
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Данные в TextBox я хочу брать из `String[]`.
Может кто-нибудь скинет туториал.

Cпасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вебе, если без подгрузки (т.е. использования ajax), придется все варианты сразу обозначить на веб-странице, например, в js-переменной и также js-скриптом можно подгрузить в поле ввода.
Либо заранее создать html-список всех вариантов и использовать его при помощи datalist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList"/>
  <datalist id="languageList">
     <option value="HTML" />
     <option value="CSS" />
     <option value="JavaScript" />
     <option value="SQL" />
     <option value="PHP" />
     <option value="jQuery" />
     <option value="Bootstrap" />
     <option value="Angular" />
     <option value="ASP.NET" />
     <option value="XML" />
 </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

[Источник](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/create-auto-complete-dropdown-using.html)

Пример загрузки из массива Strings[]:
HTML код ASP.Net страницы:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxInput" runat="server" list="myList"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblmyList" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Функция в коде загрузки страницы:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] myArray = new String[] { "один", "два", "три", "дважды" };
    string myList = "<datalist id='myList'>";
    foreach (string str in myArray)
    {
        myList += "<option value='" + str + "' />";
    }
    myList += "</datalist>";
    lblmyList.Text = myList;
}
```

Результат примера:

[image: результат]

Если же нужна подгрузка, но нет желания писать ajax-загрузчик самостоятельно, можно воспользоваться AutoComplete-компонентом из [библиотеки ajaxControlToolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).
Пример:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
runat="server" 
ID="autoComplete1" 
TargetControlID="myTextBox"
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true"
CompletionSetCount="20" 
CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
DelimiterCharacters=";, :">
    <Animations>
        <OnShow> ... </OnShow>
        <OnHide> ... </OnHide>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

В коде же (C#) нужно будет написать обработчик подгрузки:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) { ...
```

Comment: У меня почему-то постоянно компилятор ругался на эту библиотеку, постоянно что то не нравилось. Вот я и решил найти простой способ. Так как данные берутся из массива String'ов.

Comment: А массив большой? Есть ли смысл сразу же загружать его на страницу?

Comment: @kxxko Если без библиотеки, то используйте первый вариант. В коде при загрузки страницы заполняйте datalist из своего массива и всё.

Comment: @kxxko добавила в ответ пример загрузки из массива.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное !

Comment: Вы не подскажите мне, как сделать ограничение на этот выпадающий список ? Что-то не получается ( И если честно, то я не понял, как я могу записать в массив список из живого поиска.

Answer (score 2):

В html есть такой тег, называется datalist. Вы в нем указываете список нужных значений, а потом идентификатор этого datalist'a пишете в атрибут list вашего текстового поля. После этого ваше текстовое поле работает наподобие выпадающего списка, содержимое котооро беретсся из datalist'a, который вы можете заполнить чем угодно. Пример:

```
<input list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
   <option value="First">
   <option value="Second">
   <option value="Third">
</datalist>
```

Тот же пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8myL7u0/)
Использование ajax тут необязательно (хотя при желании можно прикрутить заполнение datalist'a и с помощью запроса), можно заполнять его при рендеринге страницы на сервере.

Пример для ASP.NET:

```
<input list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
   <%
       foreach (var str in Strings) 
       {%>
           <option><%= str%></option>
    <% } %>
</datalist>
```

Где Strings - ваш массив строк. Например такой:

```
    public string[] Strings
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                "First",
                "Second",
                "Third",
                "Fourth"
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как можно заполнять value значениями из массива ?
Можно ли это делать не в html, а С# ?

Comment: @kxxko добавил пример для ASP.NET

Comment: Спасибо, помогло ! Хорошего Вам дня =)